# Primefaces editor puts options into the text

Tags: java, primefaces

I am using p:editor for an input as:

```
<p:editor id="editor" value="#{blogUIBean.blogEdit.blogIn}" required="true" style="width:500px"/>
```

And I'm displaying this input as:

```
 <h:outputText value="#{blogUIBean.selectedBlog.blogIn}" style="line-height:150%;margin-left:30px;background-color:#e1ecf0;" />
```

But it is displayed with the editor options selected like;  span style="font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 18px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">Projenin fikir babası olan Ekmek Sanayi İşverenler Sendikası, sundukları projenin büyük bir ilgi ile karşılandığını ve

Why is this happening and how can I disable these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use attribute `escape` like:

```
<h:outputText value="#{blogUIBean.selectedBlog.blogIn}" escape="false" style="line-height:150%;margin-left:30px; background-color:#e1ecf0;" />
```

> escape
>
> Flag indicating that characters that are sensitive in
>   HTML and XML markup must be escaped. This flag is
>   set to "true" by default.